# How to rewrite this using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a simple way to rewrite this snippet using list comprehension?

```
f_list = []
for f in file_list:
    if os.path.isfile(SC_JSON_DIR + f + ".json"):
        f_list.append(f)
return f_list
```

Comment: Probably nitpicking but `os.path.join(SC_JSON_DIR, "".join([f, ".json"]))` seems more "pythonic" to me rather than string concatenation in `os.path.isfile`. Might help even if `SC_JSON_DIR` ends or not with a [back]slash.

Comment: @Neitsa: `''.join()` for two elements is hardly pythonic. You can just use concatenation for just two elements. :-) `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(SC_JSON_DIR, f + ".json"))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
return [f for f in file_list if os.path.isfile(SC_JSON_DIR + f + ".json")]
```

Comment: You could even return the list comprehension directly without assigning it to `f_list`. So to shorten it even more `return [f for f in file_list if os.path.isfile(SC_JSON_DIR + f + ".json")]` will do the trick.

Comment: @Neitsa While that is a very useful comment and certainly one I would implement in my program, the question assignment was to `rewrite this snippet` using list comprehension.  I'm trying to keep it as similar as possible, but with list comprehension.  I think a more suitable place for that comment is at the question.